# how to avoid escaping chracters PHP

Tags: php, urlencode, urldecode

I have a string, `$bodoy= 'this is data \\u003d\ this is data';` I want to `urlencode()` it, but when I `urldecode()` it gives me string like this. `'this is data \u003d\ this is data';`

Note: I can't change the string, since it is coming from a thirdparty. Only want to ignore the escape sequences. so the result will same, after `urldecode()`

Required Result: `this is data \\u003d\ this is data`

Answer (score 0):

`urlencode()` and `urldecode()` are irrelevant, it is because of how you are entering the string in the source code.

To get the literal string `this is data \\u003d\ this is data` from a string assignment in PHP source code enclosed in double quotes, single quotes, or a HEREDOC you must escape *all* of the backslashes.

Eg:

```
$string = 'this is data \\\\u003d\\ this is data';
$string = "this is data \\\\u003d\\ this is data";
$string = <<<_E_
this is data \\\\u003d\\ this is data
_E_;
```

This is because `\` is *always* an escape character which must itself be escaped. A lone backslash does not necessarily need to be escaped, but if you don't then a following character can be interpreted as an escape sequence, such as `\\` collapsing to `\` as you've seen.

The exception being the NOWDOC, where there is no escaping at all.

```
$string = <<<'_E_'
this is data \\u003d\ this is data
_E_;
```

Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: how can I add a variable in NOWDOC. if I have my string is `$dt=this is data \\u003d\ this is data`

Comment: @MuhammadArslanJamshaid _"how can I add a variable in NOWDOC"_ - you can't. Quote manual: _"A nowdoc is specified similarly to a heredoc, **but no parsing is done inside a nowdoc**."_